# Call external js function file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a scientific calculator and I've addded a feature that solves linear equations too. [Here](http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/calcolatrice/calcolatricecs.html) you can see the link to the page. When you click on `Sistemi` you see a new page with some input fields and the button "Solve".

```
<form name="sis1grado" action="sistema1.js">
<p align="center"><input id="x1" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px"> x  +  <input id="x2" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px"> y  =  <input id="x3" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px"></p>
<p align="center"><input id="x4" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px"> x  +  <input id="x5" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px"> y  =  <input id="x6" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px"></p>
<br>
<table width="216px" border="0" align="center">
<td width="16px">
<img src="http://i1087.photobucket.com/albums/j475/BetoMan0/graffapar.png" />
</td>
<td width="90px">
x = <input id="totx" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px">
<br>
<br>
y = <input id="toty" type="text" name="usrname" style="width:42px">
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Solve"></p>
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the code of the "Sistemi" page. In the same folder as `calcolatricecs.html` I have a js file called `sistema1.js`. It contains a function, called s1(), that has the code I must use for solve the equation ([click here](http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/calcolatrice/sistema1.js) to see that the js file).

When I click the button Solve I'd like solve the equation calling the s1() function. To do this, I put `<form name="sis1grado" action="sistema1.js">` and I also gave to my input the attribute `submit` as you can see.

This way is not working to me because when I click the button, anything happen. What could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `onclick` handler to your button:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Solve" onclick="s1();">
```

Also, be sure to reference your JS file with `<script>` tags.

Comment: Do I have to remove `action="sistema1.js"` ?

Comment: I've made what you said, but it doesn't work. If you look at my page, click Sistemi, try to fill the gaps with some numbers and press Solve, anything happen

Comment: I see in the console that `s1 is not defined`, are you referencing your external JS anywhere? I didn't see it in the page source.

Comment: http://www.mk7vrlist.altervista.org/calcolatrice/sistema1.js --> this is the full path, so I put action="/calcolatrice/sistema1.js"

Comment: You need to make a reference to the actual script `<script src="sistema1.js"></script>`

Comment: So once I put that I should be ok?

Comment: Yes, since there is no reference to the script right now, it has no idea what `s1();` is when it's being called.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been very helpful :)